# How to get Safari to open links in the corresponding tab for the site?

Tags: safari

1. Say I have a Safari tab with Gmail loaded, for instance showing:

   ```
   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
   ```
2. In my todo app, I have a link, like the shown below, which points to a specific thread.

   ```
   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FMfcgxvzLNXbTXWNCQMHTVtJlDXVpwXs
   ```

When I click on this link, it opens a new tab in Safari. How can I instead get Safari to open that link in the existing Gmail tab, based on the URL without the fragment identifier being the same in both cases? I used Gmail as an example, but it would be nice if the solution was generic, and worked with any site using fragment identifiers (e.g. WorkFlowy).

Certainly, I can copy the URL, switch to Safari, switch to the Gmail tab, ⌘L, ⌘V, enter. This is what I do now, but just being able to open the link would be much faster.

The main reason for wanting this is that when opening a new tab, Safari reloads Gmail, which takes a few seconds. Opening the link in the existing tab is *much* faster.

Comment: what "to do app" ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Ideally, I'd like this to work independently of the todo app being used, whether OmniFocus, Things, or something else.

Comment: maybe I do not understand (it happens often), you can tell Safari not to open new tab but instead open in the existing tab. Is it that your are talking about ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Correct: open the link in an existing tab for the same app, if it exists.